# running multiple exe files using loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

Suppose I have three folders named 0, 1 and 2. there are three .exe files in these three foldres named a.exe. Is it possible to run these  .exe files inside the specific folders using a loop in batch file ?

I have made a batch file in the following way but it is not working:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,2) DO (

 ./%%A/a.exe
)
```

is there anything wrong?

Comment: Try using backslashes `\` instead of forward slashes `/` as in windows backslashes are directory-separators and forward slashes switch option-indicators

Comment: will i write in this way? .\%%A\a.exe @user76289

Comment: Yes - not guaranteed, but may make a difference depending on what `a.exe` does.

Comment: `.\%%A\a.exe` only works in case the directories `0`, `1`, `2` are located in the *current working directory*; if they are placed in the parent directory of the patch script, write `"%~dp0%%A\a.exe"` instead; or even use absolute paths...

Comment: not working @Magoo

Comment: Where are the folders in relation to your batch file?

Comment: folders are in current directory @Squashman

Comment: Just use `"%%A\a.exe"`

Comment: @user76289 when you say "not working" how is it not working? What error message do you get?

Comment: will it run the exe files inside the specific folders or in currenr directory? @Squashman

Comment: I mean the exe files are supposed to be run inside the specific folders but it isn't @user76289

Comment: Instead of `%%A\a.exe`, do `cd %%A && a.exe`.

Comment: will I write this? FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,2) DO (

 cd %%A && a.exe
) @Klitos Kyriacou

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, you are missing a line of code.  You need to do a `CD ..` after the program executes.

Comment: @Squashman well spotted.
`FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,2) DO (pushd %%A && a.exe & popd)`